# Multiple MSQL tables and foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yii

I wanted to know what is the better approach (performance wise) when working with Yii and mysql tables:

1. 1 table with ALL the columns
2. multiple tables (distribute the columns across them) with foreign keys relations

basically, what i'm asking is: 
Is there any performance degradation when a single table has many relations since Yii will fetch all the corresponding tables into the object when you do a query?

A more general question is: what is good practice and smarter approach when dealing with 1 vs multiple tables and foreign keys (again performance..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If performance was the **only** criteria in your design strategy, you would choose 1. A very bad choice, that would give you a lot of problems in a later stage of your problems.

Databases should be designed with **normalization** in mind, so without any doubt, you must choose option 2!

**Update**

Example of normalized and not normalized: suppose we have a table with dvd rentals, and want to keep track of who rented the dvd:

flat table:

```
CREATE TABLE DVD (
  DvdId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  DvdTitle varchar(64),
  Rental1 varchar(64), 
  Rental2 varchar(64), 
  Rental3 varchar(64),
  Primary Key(DvdId)
);
```

There is room for 3 rental entries, after that there is trouble. Beside that, when there is a extra field needed for the phone number of the customers, 3 extra fields must be made.

First step normalization:

```
CREATE TABLE DVD (
  DvdId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  DvdTitle varchar(64),
  Primary Key(DvdId)
);

CREATE TABLE Rentals (
  RentalId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  DvdId INT NOT NULL, 
  CustomerName varchar(64),
  RentalDate DateTime,
  Primary Key(RentalId)
);
```

This is better, but still not fully normalized. What if a customer rents the same dvd twice. Then there would be a double customer entry in the rentals table.

Final:

```
CREATE TABLE DVD (
  DvdId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  DvdTitle varchar(64),
  Primary Key(DvdId)
);

CREATE TABLE Rentals (
  RentalId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  DvdId INT NOT NULL, 
  CustomerId INT NOT NULL, 
  RentalDate DateTime,
  Primary Key(RentalId)
);

CREATE TABLE Customers (
  CustomerId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  CustomerName varchar(64),
  Primary Key(CustomerId)
);
```

Comment: thanks @jvdBerg, can you elaborate on normalization? what about the way Yii get the relations - what do you think is the better approach on that matter?

Comment: I don't know about Yii, but database design and Yii have nothing in common. Every decent framework will expect a normalized database. I Will cook a example about normalization.

Answer (score 1):

The better option is to design your database properly complying normalisation rules.
Here are some quick links about them:

http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

http://moryadesigns.wordpress.com/2009/09/08/rules-of-data-normalization-sql/

**1NF** Eliminate Repeating Groups – Make a separate table for each set of
related attributes, and give each table a primary key.

**2NF** Eliminate Redundant Data – If an attribute depends on only part of a
multi-valued key, remove it to a separate table.

**3NF** Eliminate Columns Not Dependent On Key – If attributes do not
contribute to a description of the key, remove them to a separate table.

**BCNF**    Boyce-Codd Normal Form – If there are non-trivial dependencies between candidate key
attributes, separate them out into distinct tables.

**4NF** Isolate Independent Multiple Relationships – No table may contain
two or more 1:n or n:m relationships that are not directly related.

**5NF** Isolate Semantically Related Multiple Relationships – There may be
practical constrains on information that justify separating logically related many-to-many
relationships.

**ONF** Optimal Normal Form – a model limited to only simple (elemental)
facts, as expressed in Object Role Model notation.

**DKNF**    Domain-Key Normal Form – a model free from all modification anomalies.

Yii uses extensive lazy-loading and the will not load related elements until you ask for them and use them.